# UTF8 encoding unable to decode

Tags: encoding, utf-8, iconv

I got a XML file which is full of utf-8 strings from French. Some messages are as follows:

"N'oubliez pas d'Ã©crire le nom exact de le professeur, sans utiliser des abrÃ©viations"

As you can see, accents are failing. I tried to convert the file with iconv but seems that is not recognised as UTF-8 (when the file is using that charset). What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't said what you're doing with the file after decoding it - e.g. whether you're displaying it (and how), converting it to a different encoding etc.

Comment: I bet this file uses ISO-8859-1 encoding, so use this encoding to read it properly.

Comment: This looks exactly like UTF-8 encoded file read to ANSI encoded string. Please read file specifying correct character set...

Comment: @Paweł: There’s no such thing as “ANSI”.  It does look like UTF-8 misinterpreted as ISO 8859-1, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in Windows Notepad and see how it looks. If it looks fine, then the issue is likely somewhere else (eg. are you sending the data to a browser and not specifying UTF-8?).

If it looks wrong in Notepad too, try the following (I copied your data into a file and was able to "fix" it by doing this):

- Open in Notepad
- File -> Save As -> Select "ANSI" and Save
- Open the new file in Notepad
- File -> Save As -> Select UTF-8 and Save

This final file should open correctly in Notepad and be encoded as UTF-8 with a three-byte UTF-8 signature.